# JMS Serializer null-aware deserialization

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I would greatly appreciate information whether it is possible (and how) to configure JMS Serializer **deserializer** to be aware of nullables from PHP7.1 - for example if I'm trying to deserialize into class:

```
class Foo {
    /** @Type("string") **/
    private $test;
}
```

It will not accept empty json dictionary, but into:

```
class Foo { 
    /** @Type("string|null") **/
    private $test;
}
```

will do. For custom configuration there is no requirement for a field to exist - it will accept empty dictionary for first example of class.